# What are the risks having visited a counterfeit or phishing web page on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, malware

I received from a regular colleague a sharing e-mail in iOS Outlook, and clicked the link. It opened a web page asking for my credentials, which I did not enter because I recognized the page as counterfeit.

1. Is there any way to tell whether simply visiting the page resulted in a drive-by injection?
2. Is there anything I should do to ensure my device is as clean as it was before clicking the link?
3. Is there a reason to uninstall and reinstall Outlook on the phone?

### Technical Details

- iOS 14.0.1 ;
- Microsoft Outlook for iOS 4.57.2 ;
- iPhone Xs Max

Comment: The Outlook App for iOS has a feature that allows you to report Junk and Phishing attempts directly to Microsoft for them to analyze.  Make sure you flag it as a phishing attempt.

Comment: @Allan Thanks. They're aware. It was a spoof of their sharing invitation, and I was in conversation with their engineers concerning the person from whom it appeared to come. Her account had been compromised, and we were trying to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

It's very unlikely that you were infected with anything or that anything negative happened overall if you did not enter your credentials. My reasoning for this is as follows:

1. It asked for your credentials, which indicates the goal was phishing not infecting your devices
2. Drive-by infections are not impossible, but they're also **not easy**. Unless you're a high profile target it's unlikely you would ever interact with one.

I don't believe there is any reason to be concerned based on how you described this.